# Question: Lua for i, v print value with aligned \t

Tags: lua

I explain i actually do a trrtable function

work like this :

```
local function treeTable(obj)
    if type(obj) == "table" then
        for i, v in pairs(obj) do
            print(tostring(i) .. "\t-> <" .. type(v) .. "> " .. tostring(v))
        end
    else
        print("Not allow '" .. type(obj) .. "' value.")
    end
end

local table = {
    Number = 1,
    String = "Hello world",
    Boolean = true,
    Table = { Name = "Jessica", Age = 19 },
    Function = function() print("Hi") end
}

treeTable(table)
```

Output :

```
Number  -> <number> 1
String  -> <string> Hello world
Table   -> <table> table: 009E94A8
Boolean -> <boolean> true
Function    -> <function> function: 009EBA10
```

But i want the output is seem like this :

```
Number      -> <number> 1
String      -> <string> Hello world
Table       -> <table> table: 009E94A8
Boolean     -> <boolean> true
Function    -> <function> function: 009EBA10
```

But i don't know how can i do this, i've search on stackoverflow and i found nothing for me :/

Comment: Replace `tostring(i)` with `('%-8s'):format(tostring(i))`